# How do I keep textarea line breaks when fwrite with php?

Tags: php, html

I am making a text bin like pastebin or hastebin.

In my index.php I have: [index.php](http://hastebin.com/vusaginixi.xml)

In my uploader.php I have: [uploader.php](http://hastebin.com/ahuxafuhon.php)

When I do that, the output does everything I want but in the .txt it will break a line but on the php post it wont. E.g.

In .txt file:

```
Hello
Hello
```

would show up as

```
Hello 
Hello
```

but in the php it would show up as

```
Hello Hello
```

Can someone please help me?

Note: I'm running on localhost but I'm gonna upload it to my site!

Comment: View the source and it will be right. What are you missing? HTML. If you're going to view it as a web page you need HTML for formatting.

Comment: Use `nl2br()` to convert newlines to HTML `<br>` tags.

Comment: Or put it in a `<pre>...</pre>` block.

Comment: well i tried nl2br($mystring); and it didnt work

Comment: WAIT NVM! THX SO MUCH! i had to do it like $data = nl2br($data);

Answer (score 1):

Been here before.
I hope you are using mysqli_real_escape_string to save into database or PDO. Its safe and prevent errors.

When outputting your content use nl2br. For example:

```
<?php  echo nl2br($mystring);  ?>
```

This will preserve line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you are displaying the text in HTML format, is to put all of the text inside a `<pre>` block:

```
<pre>Hello
Hello</pre>
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it like: http://hastebin.com/ayuyuvonuq without having to do anything like that?

Comment: You can put all the text inside `<pre></pre>`. Try if that works.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it puts a space like http://hastebin.com/uyenocosoy